# CSS positioning and jQuery .animate

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering how you would make an element (aka div class="popu") not be affected by the jquery .animate. I dont want the white dialog boxes to move but I do want the imgs to move under it, I tried

```
position:absolute;
```

But they still move. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8g84C/
Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by changing your markup and css positioning declarations. But if you wanted to do it in javascrictp within your existing function you could just add a negative margin that has the same value as the animated margin

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8g84C/1/

```
$("#e").click(function () {
     $("#re").animate({
         "margin-top": "104px"
     }, 800);
     $(".popu").animate({
         "margin-top": "-104px"
     }, 800);
     $("#ret").animate({
         "margin-top": "104px"
     }, 800);
 });
```